# Mail Attachment in ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Am trying to add an attachment to mail in asp.net VB.

I could send mail fine until I added the attachment code,

```
Dim attch As Attachment = New Attachment("http://sitehere.com/Documents/file.jpg")
mail.Attachments.Add(attch)
```

I am getting the error URI formats are not supported.

Any ideas why that is and what I can do about it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Attachment` class expects either a path to a file on the file system, or a `Stream`.

Try:

```
Dim data As Byte() = New WebClient().DownloadData("http://sitehere.com/Documents/file.jpg")
Dim attachment As New Attachment(New MemoryStream(data), "file.jpg")
```

That's me doing my best to translate from C# to VB.NET so the syntax might not be 100% correct, but that's the general idea.  That will download the data into a byte array, then create a memory stream from those bytes and pass that to the Attachment constructor.

Answer (score 1):

You can't add an attachment straight from a URL.  You'll need to download the file first, then add it as an attachment.

you can use `HttpWebRequest` to get the file as a stream, then attach the stream. That saves having to store the file on disk.

Comment: The file is already in the system, the path to it is stored in a database as a URL. I want to attach the selected file from the database to the mail, is that not possible?

Comment: If you have a URL that maps to a local path, you just need to reverse that mapping and then you can add the original file.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the file locally in your server and in a folder which you know the path, dont use the uri for that,

```
 Dim eMessage As New MailMessage

 Dim attachLabel As Attachment
 Dim location As String
 loction= Server.MapPath("Documents\\file.jpg")
 attachLabel = New Attachment(loction)

 eMessage .Attachments.Add(attachLabel);
```

If you really want to send a file from another url, you may use `HttpWebRequest` to download that first and send it as Colin and Davy8 metnioned.